# В чём ошибка в реализации обработчика AJAX-запроса

Tags: php, ajax

Задача такая - с помощью jax-запроса передать данные на обработчик, который с полученными данными в качестве аргументов вызовет функцию.

Форма:

```
<form method="POST" id = "formx" action="javascript:void(null);" onsubmit="call(this)">
    <p>
        Кол-во бронируемых номеров:
        <select id="room_num_search" class="room_num_search" name="room_num_search">
            <?php for($i=1; $i <= $show; $i++): ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $i;  ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
            <?php endfor;  ?>
        </select>
    </p>

    <input type="submit" value="Выбрать">
</form>
```

Ajax-запрос:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function call(form) {
        var msg   = jQuery(form).serialize();
        jQuery.ajax({
            // Метод передачи
            type: 'POST',
            // Файл которому передаем запрос и получаем ответ
            url: '<?php echo '/path/to/ajax.php'   ?>',
            // Кеширование
            cache: false,
            // Верямя ожидания ответа, в мили секундах 1000 мс = 1 сек
            timeout:3000,
            data: msg,
            // Функция сработает при успешном получении данных
            success: function(data) {
                // Отображаем данные в форме
                jQuery(".results").html(data);
            },
            // Функция срабатывает в период ожидания данных
            beforeSend: function(data) {
                jQuery(".results").html('<p>Ожидание данных...</p>');
            },
            // Тип данных
            dataType:"html",
            // Функция сработает в случае ошибки
            error:  function(data){
                jQuery(".results").html('<p>Возникла неизвестная ошибка. Пожалуйста, попробуйте чуть позже...</p>');
            },
        });
    };
</script>
```

PHP-обработчик (ajax.php):

```
<?php
$room_num_search = $_POST['room_num_search'];
STHotel::qwerty($room_num_search);
?>
```

Сама вызываемая функция:

```
    static function qwerty($room_num_search){
        echo $room_num_search;
    }
```

Выходит ошибка: 500 (Internal Server Error) . Если в обработчике просто написать echo $room_num_search , то всё выводится. Но мне нужно, чтобы вызвалась функция с переданным аргументом.

Comment: Читайте логи и выясняйте в чем причина ошибки. Скорее всего, в том что скрипт не знает откуда ему взять определение класса `STHotel`.

Comment: @u_mulder, да, ошибка 100% в том, что вы сказали. Потому что вызов STHotel::qwerty($room_num_search); из обычного файла в той же директории работает, а вот через ajax-запрос - нет. Не понимаю - почему.

Comment: гуглю и нахожу инфо, что ajax для этого не приспособлен, может, я ошибаюсь

Comment: Сравните код __обычного__ файла с вашим.

Comment: @u_mulder , обычный - это какой именно?

Comment: @Alexey_Danilov видимо тот, в котором все срабатывает

Comment: @РашенБеар а чего их сравнивать? В одном не используется ajax, он срабатывает, в другом используется - он не срабатывает. Но мне нужно через ajax

Comment: @Alexey_Danilov, в скрипте `ajax.php` вы вызываете не функцию, а статический метод класса `STHotel`. Добавьте в начало скрипта ```ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);``` и сделайте запрос. Посмотрите, что он вернет

Comment: Понятное дело что вернет нечто типа `class STHotel not found`. Подлкючать файл с классом видимо кто-то другой должен.

Comment: @u_mulder , это wordpress, классы автоматически подключены

Comment: Если ваш `ajax.php` состоит из тех 4 строк, что в вопросе, то увы - ничего не подключено.